# How to avoid transparent_hugepage/defrag warning from mongodb?

Tags: linux, mongodb, linux-kernel

I'm receiving the following warning from mongodb about THP

```
2015-03-06T21:01:15.526-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-03-06T21:01:15.526-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
```

But I did manage to turned THP off manually

```
frederick@UbuntuVirtual:~$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
frederick@UbuntuVirtual:~$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always madvise [never]
```

I did the trick by adding `transparent_hugepage=never` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and adding

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

to `/etc/rc.local`

How on earth can I avoid the warning?

Comment: I had the same issue, but forgot to reboot everything, including mongod. I know it may be a stupid question, but did you reboot everything?

Comment: of course, I've rebooted the virtual machine several times.

Comment: wait... you meant restart the mongod service? oh... I ran `sudo service mongod restart` and the warning just gone! thanks! this is strange, why can't I just reboot the VM?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't catch on reboot. But yeah, I meant restarting the daemon. Glad it is working.

Comment: This is not a solution. The reason you see this warning after reboot is that mongo daemon is started before your rc.local have been executed. Restarting the daemon after system boot solve the issue, but next time when you reboot your VM you will see that nice warning again. Unfortunatelly I can't give you the solution as I'm still searching for it.

Comment: 'sudo service mongod restart' doesn't work for me

Comment: @SileNT Nope, the warning hasn't come out again since I restarted the service.

Comment: @Frederick888 Even if you reboot the VM? Restarting the service solves the warning just temporary. For more details check this issue:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17418

Comment: @SileNT well, I had restarted the VM for many times but the warning just kept coming out until I restarted the service and the warning disappeared right away. since then, even if I restart the VM, the warning won't come out again.

Comment: The extended question, that I have not yet seen, ought to be about why mongo suggests setting THP to 'never' and why it's already set to 'always.' If I'm seeing this on Google's cloud and someone already mentioned Digital Ocean, is it even a good idea to "fix" this? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: Even though the grub option sets it to never, MongoDB ignores that it is disabled, and still looks at the irrelevant setting /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag and sees it is set to "always", then complains.  This is a MongoDB bug.

Comment: Known bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-5108

Comment: On Ubuntu Server 16.04, this worked for me (https://askubuntu.com/a/820116/723672).

Comment: @mightypile Right. Shouldn’t it actually be best to set it to `madvise` so that applications which benefit from THT and set `MADV_HUGEPAGE` can still benefit from it instead of disabling it systemwide?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

[Official MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/transparent-huge-pages/#transparent-huge-pages-thp-settings) gives several solutions for this issue. You can also try [this solution](http://christina04.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/12/130033), which worked for me:

Note: Try official documentation directives *if MongoDB version is greater than 3.0*

1. Open `/etc/init.d/mongod` file. 
   (if no such file you might check `/etc/init.d/mongod`, `/etc/init/mongod.conf` files - credit: the below comments)
2. Add the lines below immediately after `chown $DAEMONUSER /var/run/mongodb.pid` and before `end script`.
3. Restart `mongod` (`service mongod restart`).

Here are the lines to add to `/etc/init.d/mongod`:

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

That's it!

Comment: Sorry that I didn't accept your answer immediately. I comment the lines I added to rc.local out and tried your solution, and it did work for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: welll, I did not find a /etc/init/mongod.conf file, but I did add those lines into the /etc/init.d/mongod script file, just before the echo "Starting..." line, and it works for me

Comment: awesome solution! works on Ubuntu 14.04 and mongod 3.

Comment: This works please add alternate entry for /etc/init/mongod.conf    for Ubuntu users. gracias.

Comment: I am using mongodb on ubuntu where my conf file is in YAML format. Is there an alternate solution applicable there as well ?

Comment: @PraveshJain, in the above solution uses `if` conditional structure and I don't know how to prepare a [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) for if conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately, whenever I run $sudo yum update (on AWS EC2 instance) , the content of the file /etc/init.d/mongod. gets reset. And the hugepage defrag warning come back. What can I do? Thanks @efkan

Comment: I never think about what happens when I run update command @ScottMayers. If so we might evaluate the official solutions. And so far that works for me perfectly.

Comment: Is this something I should do if I'm running MongoDB on my personal laptop? The documentation says that THP is not optimal for MongoDB, but is it optimal for normal operating procedures? Would using this new setting slow down my computer during normal use?

Comment: I don't know really. But if I were you I would turn THP off by taking into account the official MongoDB explanation.

Comment: just to point out a typo in your answer: 
`$DEAMONUSER` ===> `$DAEMONUSER`

Comment: `chown $DAEMONUSER /var/run/mongodb.pid` is not found in `/etc/init.d/mongod` and nor is `end script`

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 18, installed v3.4.2, and the file now is /etc/init.d/mongodb

Answer (score 26):

MongoDB have updated their recommendation to use an **init.d** script now:
http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

Comment: This is the correct answer for ubuntu 16.04 and above

Answer (score 10):

For Ubuntu 14.04 using upstart:

Since we are deploying machines with Ansible I don't like modifying rc files or GRUB configs.

I tried using `sysfsutils` / `sysfs.conf` but ran into timing issues when starting the services on fast (or slow machines). It looked like sometimes mongod was started before sysfsutils. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it did not.

Since mongod is an upstart process I found that the cleanest solution was to add the file `/etc/init/mongod_vm_settings.conf` with the following content:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongod_vm_settings.conf
#
#   This file will set the correct kernel VM settings for MongoDB
#   This file is maintained in Ansible

start on (starting mongod)
script
  echo "never" > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
  echo "never" > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
end script
```

This will run the script just before mongod will be started.
Restart mongod (`sudo service mongod restart`) and done.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open /etc/default/grub

   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
2. Update 
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="transparent_hugepage=never"
3. Save file 
   :wq (in vi)
4. Run update-grub

   sudo update-grub
5. Reboot machine

Update: If you are using a virtual hosting provider, this will work IFF grub boot is supported. DigitalOcean DOES NOT support grub boot.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... (Yes, I have my own Linux machine, with grub boot)... :(

Comment: Note that if you're using some of the solutions mentioned here, on a system that also runs 'tuned', tuned may override those solutions. See here for more info: bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1189868

Answer (score 6):

Verified that the defrag is examined without regard to the enabled:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
[always] madvise never
$ service mongod start
... (in log) WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'
$ echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always madvise [never]
$ service mongod stop
$ service mongod start
... (no warning in log)
```

Therefore, the fix to this bug is to first look at transparent_hugepage/enabled, and if it is never, don't bother looking at the irrelevant transparent_hugepage/defrag setting.

[Source](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-5108).

Comment: Working on Oracle Linux 7, the defrag never went away after the recommended changes.. finally a big sigh of relief!! this answer needs more upvotes!! I spent 4 hours digging this.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 16.04 using systemd:

`systemctl edit mongod`

Paste the following:

```
[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag"
```

Comment: worked for Centos 7 in /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service too

Comment: @shortsteps - do not edit the package systemd service file directly.  An update of the package will overwrite your settings.  Always use `systemctl edit package` to set an override.