# Mongodb startup warnings after update

Tags: mongodb

I updated the mongodb using

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

mongodb is updated from 2.4 to 3.0. Soon after I connected to mongo shell, it is displaying the below start up warnings. I am unaware of fixing it. Suggest me how to fix these warnings?

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test  
Server has startup warnings: 
2015-04-03T13:37:53.536+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-04-03T13:37:53.536+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:        /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-04-03T13:37:53.536+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-04-03T13:37:53.536+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-04-03T13:37:53.537+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-04-03T13:37:53.537+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-04-03T13:37:53.537+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding the following lines preceding exit 0 in /etc/rc.local file with root privileges did the magic. Rebooted the OS after saving the file.Then warnings disappeared in the mongo shell.

Source: MongoDB documentation(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/transparent-huge-pages/#transparent-huge-pages-thp-settings)

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag; then
echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
```

Comment: The current (=2015/09) official MongoDB docs go a slightly different way (not using /etc/rc.local but a dedicated startup script), have a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/ This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: I tried the way suggested in the official documentation and it didn't work for me (go figure). However, putting this in the rc.local works.

Is there any downside of using rc.local instead?

Comment: rc.local file is  executed by the operating system after each boot at the last run level meaning it runs afters all process and services are started by the operating system.  I see there is no downside of using it

Answer (score 6):

Those warnings pop up due to Transparent Huge Pages (THP) settings.

As stated in the [official MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/transparent-huge-pages/#transparent-huge-pages-thp-settings):

> However, THP is known to perform poorly under database workloads,
>   which tend to have sparse rather than contiguous memory access
>   patterns. You must disable THP on Linux machines used to run MongoDB
>   instances to ensure best performance.

There is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911634/how-to-avoid-transparent-hugepage-defrag-warning-from-mongodb) on StackOverflow where you can find a possible solution that recommends updating the `mongod.conf` file so that you overwrite the THP properties indicated by MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of people are having the same issue. You can find the answer in the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/transparent-huge-pages/#transparent-huge-pages-thp-settings), or you can look at a similar question that was asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911634/how-to-avoid-transparent-hugepage-defrag-warning-from-mongodb).

One person suggested typing in the console `sudo service mongod restart`, which worked for them.

Comment: Following the MongoDB documentation helped me to solve the issue