# Mongo startup warning & records are getting corrupted

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

This is what I get when i start to work on mongo on my server.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.11
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-05-04T12:40:04.269+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Due to above error my data in mongo is getting corrupted.

For example. _id of the collection change automatically from NumberLong to any random negative value (without datatype NumberLong) Queries of the database are not working as well.

I am using mongo to store my groups information. Groups are getting created just like before but its _id is automatically getting into negative value. Which then do not system to ready the data from the server.

Data Example:

Old entry:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong("5832929604864"), "battles" : [ "1478882936384", "1474596010496", "1475809103872", "1470752181248", "1475980114432", "1478966261248" ], "cat" : "57", "created_by" : "3697315148736", "date" : "2015-10-16 17:21:41", "description" : "Amazing night for houston texansqa\nAll undone with one game ending.", "is_deleted" : NumberLong(0), "members" : [ "3697315148736", "3695601014400", "3692104837824", "3690345909504", "3698247126528" ], "title" : "nfl" }
```

Automatically changing values, here's a new group created:

```
{ "_id" : -1535373376, "created_by" : "3692102996096", "title" : "fsf", "lowcase_title" : "fsf", "date" : "2016-04-18 06:02:45", "cat" : "988", "description" : "sfsdf", "members" : [ "3692102996096" ], "battles" : [ ], "is_deleted" : 0 }
```

_id: from above record converted to negative value and so "is_deleted".

Also both the above records are no longer being readed using my queries.

The same code and database is working fine on my first server.

Recently I copied my website on a different server for testing. Both the servers are on amazon's ec2 server.
On previous server when I access mongo I get this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
```

No error and every thing is working fine on this server.

Can the version of mongo causing this error or

```
I need to set 
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always' to 'never
```

If above, then can you please guide me what & how to set it to 'never'?

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429152/mongodb-startup-warnings-after-update

Comment: Thanks titi23, i wonder how you find these solutions here, i tried looking for existing answers but failed, so posted my query.