# transparent_hugepage/defrag warning in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, centos

I get a warning, when enter mongo shell

```
** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
**        We suggest setting it to 'never'
```

even I've appended the following option to the kernel command line in grub.conf:

```
transparent_hugepage=never
```

Checking

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled
always [never]
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/defrag
[always] never
```

And yes, I reboot the machine after changing GRUB options and restart mongod service.

GRUB version

```
$ grub-install -v
grub-install (GNU GRUB 0.97)
```

CentOS version

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Comment: Could you check this out; http://stackoverflow.com/a/29181918/3765109

Comment: I solved it the same way, thanks, but I wondered why defrag option still active, when I turned off THP by setting kernel option in GRUB

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command as root:

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag;
then   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag;
fi
```

Then check if it worked:

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Should give this output:

```
always madvise [never]
```