# Mongo DB Server Startup Warnings

Tags: mongodb

I've seen others with startup warnings but I can't seem find anything on this one. A few notes I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 my mongo version is 3.0.5 (I've also tried 3.0.6 with similar issues) I've tried stoping/ restarting to no avail.

It seems to be looking for a file that does not exist so I'm not sure if anyone is aware of what this file is for. Here is the log I get upon start up ($ mongo)

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2015-09-04T23:25:54.707-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] unable to validate readahead settings due to error: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/sys/dev/block/8:1/queue/read_ahead_kb"
2015-09-04T23:25:54.707-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] for more information, see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Cannot detect if NUMA interleaving is enabled. Failed to probe "/sys/devices/system/node/node1": Permission denied
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 W CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage": Permission denied
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 W CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage": Permission denied
2015-09-04T23:25:54.793-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

I can't locate `"/sys/dev/block/8:1/queue/read_ahead_kb"` which it is looking for and citing permission denied, mongo was installed via root if that makes a difference.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? I've done multiple mongo installs and haven't come across this before.

Comment: this post might help you (it is related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911634/how-to-avoid-transparent-hugepage-defrag-warning-from-mongodb

Comment: it looks like a permissions issue; aren't you starting the mongo service with: `$ sudo service mongod start`?

Comment: @woohoo I did start it with sudo, I've looked at the that topic before it's not related, I have those settings mentioned by the other poster. I should note though it appears to work fine, it import my mongodump fine and I can query/insert without errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the exact same issues with OVH/Kimsufi due to their custom kernel installed by default.

**First, you need to have first the regular ubuntu kernel and not one modified by your hosting company.**

Then, you need to disable transparent huge pages to remove the warning and improve memory performance related to memory management:

1. Add this script as `/etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepage`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          disable-transparent-hugepages
   # Required-Start:    $local_fs
   # Required-Stop:
   # X-Start-Before:    mongod mongodb-mms-automation-agent
   # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
   # Short-Description: Disable Linux transparent huge pages
   # Description:       Disable Linux transparent huge pages, to improve
   #                    database performance.
   ### END INIT INFO

   case $1 in
     start)
       if [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage ]; then
         thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage
       elif [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage ]; then
         thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage
       else
         return 0
       fi

       echo 'never' > ${thp_path}/enabled
       echo 'never' > ${thp_path}/defrag

       unset thp_path
       ;;
   esac
   ```
2. Make the script executable `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepage`
3. Register it at boot `sudo update-rc.d disable-transparent-hugepage defaults`

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

Comment: You have a typo: Script name is "/etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepage" not "/etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepages" I give feedback if this works after server restart :)

Comment: After system restart and mongodb service restart it works! Thanks!

Comment: Is it there an option to avoid the issue without reinstalling the OS on OVH with the regular kernel?  Do you know what exactly does the modified kernel has and what will be affected (monitoring tools? access?) if I reinstall with the default kernel?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did the script but I have always this warning. Do you have another solution ?

Comment: for centos change topic 4 to: 
`sudo systemctl enable disable-transparent-hugepage`

Answer (score 0):

I am adding my solution as it may be helpful for those who look for an alternative solution using tuned.

For RHEL 7 virtual machines I use this solution, it should work for non-VMs also. There is a tuned daemon running on the servers and I use that to address the issue.

I put the following 2 files into the "/etc/tuned/mongodb" folder. The .conf file is referencing the "virtual-guest" settings that came with the builds on the VM farm, to preserve the settings that are necessary for VMs and then I change only the parameters that are needed for MongoDB. The script part is necessary as the only way to change the defrag parameter was through script.

```
# /etc/tuned/mongodb/tuned.conf
[main]
include=virtual-guest

[vm]
transparent_hugepages=never

[script]
script=mongodb.sh
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/tuned/mongodb/mongodb.sh

. /usr/lib/tuned/functions

start() {
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
    return 0
}

stop() {
    return 0
}

process $@
```

Make the "/etc/tuned/mongodb/mongodb.sh" executable and make the "/etc/tuned/mongodb" folder recursively owned by root:root.

Then use the "tuned-adm" command to check and change the active profile.

```
sudo tuned-adm active
Current active profile: virtual-guest
```

then

```
sudo tuned-adm profile mongodb
```

then

```
sudo tuned-adm active
Current active profile: mongodb
```

After this, the huge-pages settings should be OK for MongoDB.