# Mongo DB Server Startup Warnings Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage"

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I have newly installed mongodb version 3.0.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
When I connect to mongo I have startup warnings:

```
connecting to: localhost:27017/admin
Server has startup warnings:
2015-12-17T16:53:14.612+0100 W CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-12-17T16:53:14.612+0100 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage": Permission denied
2015-12-17T16:53:14.612+0100 W CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-12-17T16:53:14.612+0100 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage": Permission denied
2015-12-17T16:53:14.612+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: it seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409303/mongo-db-server-startup-warnings