# service mongod status "Active: failed ..."

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, database

When i tape this command to show the status of mongodb

> sudo service mongod status

i have this error output

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
```

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-07-06 12:57:03 CEST; 3min 52s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 6233 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 6233 (code=exited, status=100)

Jul 06 12:57:03 ns3067256.ip-94-23-35.eu systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jul 06 12:57:03 ns3067256.ip-94-23-35.eu mongod[6233]: 2017-07-06T12:57:03.090+0200 I CONTROL  [main] WARNING: Cannot detect if NUMA interleaving is enabled. Failed to pr
Jul 06 12:57:03 ns3067256.ip-94-23-35.eu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Jul 06 12:57:03 ns3067256.ip-94-23-35.eu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 06 12:57:03 ns3067256.ip-94-23-35.eu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

so what is the solution !?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409303/mongo-db-server-startup-warnings

Answer (score 0):

Go to /etc/mongod.conf and look for dbPath: /xyz/xyz

Use the following command to provide the rights to mongodb

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /xyz/xyz
```