# mongod command "corrupting" MongoDb installation?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have installed MongoDB 3.2.1. I had various problems with it that I fixed by either finding help from the internet (thanks Google) or by uninstalling and re-installing MongoDb.

One persistent problem that I cannot fix, unless I re-install, is by running `mongod` on the terminal. Currently my mongodb installation is working properly. With `sudo service mongod start` I start mongodb (I commented out start on xxxx line at /etc/init/mongod.conf so it doesn't auto start.) and with `sudo service mongod stop` I can stop it normally atm. And it correctly uses /var/lib/mongodb path for saving my collections.

If however after I stop mongodb with `sudo service mongod stop` I hit, on the terminal, `mongod` then mongodb breaks. I have gotten all kinds of errors like

- Unusable mongod.lock. I have gotten around it, in a previous install, by doing `sudo mongod` but that was not a proper solution.
- /data/db folder not found !!. Why look for it in the first place? The /etc/mongod.conf specifies the dbpath /var/lib/mongodb which is also the default when mongodb gets installed !!?? I have gotten around it as well with the `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb` option.

I think there was one more error that I don't remember but I also fixed/gotten_around it by finding solutions online.

I know that by re-installing and by never running mongod I can - for now? - not face those problems again (which looks a much better solution that the "workarounds" I did whenever those problems arose. I am wondering however what it is that is going wrong when I type `mongod` instead of `sudo service mongod start` ?!

In case somebody tries to replicate the problem know that I ve done only two modifications on my system after installing:

1. Commenting out the start on xxxx line at /etc/init/mongod.conf
2. Disabling transparent hugepages as described on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911634/how-to-avoid-transparent-hugepage-defrag-warning-from-mongodb).
   I don't think anyone of those should interfere with my installation.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on? Aren't those commands supposed to do the same thing??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will try to answer.

First, unless you know what you are doing, you should not start mongod manually.

In general (a bit simplified), calling `[sudo] service mongod start`, you instruct the system to read the according file in `/etc/init` and start the executable according to the configuration described in said file.

When you started mongod by hand, however, you actually called the `mongod` binary, the server software itself – while the name is the same as the service, the two commands have few things in common. The binary does *not* use the `/etc/mongod.conf` by default, falling back to its default values for the various settings. Actually, you can see that the config file is explicitly defined in the init script. This is why mongod tried to find `/data/db`.

You can find said binary by issuing

```
which mongod
```

Regarding the lock file: When mongod is started by the system, user root actually assumes the effective user id of `mongod` (or `mongodb` I don't know for Ubuntu of the top of my head). When you tried to start it from your user id, you do not have the privileges to overwrite the lock file. When you used `sudo mongod` afterwards, you assumed the effective user id of `root` which on the other hand is allowed to overwrite said file. However, `mongod` will the run as `root` which is a security no-no.

An init script defines which environment to use, which user to run under and a lot of other stuff. Unless you really know what you are doing, you should not even fiddle with them, much less skip it.

And now, with the finger up

> **[`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)** is ***not*** the UNIX way of saying ["I mean it!"](https://xkcd.com/149/)

It has security implications, and you should be very aware of those implications before using it – aka read the [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) of every command you issue before you use it until you have at least a fact based idea of what the command is doing.

And again: unless you really *know* (as opposed to assume) what you are doing, do not fiddle with the system configuration.

Comment: One thing that I neglected to mention is that after running mongod and getting those errors I couldn't start mongod service. It would not start!

I know changing the configuration in a system is risky but I needed to do some changes and this whole project of mine is about learning various IT related stuff. Can't do that without getting my hands dirty.

A minor question. With `which mongo` I know what binary starts, but how do I know what executes when `sudo service mongod start` is executed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Karsus Have a close look at `/etc/init/mongod`.

Comment: It says `DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod` which is the same path from `which mongod` !?

There are also these lines:
`if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGOD" = "xyes" ]
  then
    exec start-stop-daemon --start \
        --chuid $DAEMONUSER:$DAEMONGROUP \
        --pidfile /var/run/mongodb.pid \
        --make-pidfile \
        --exec $NUMACTL $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
  fi`

but while the pid is different is calls $DAEMON as well so I am not sure what to understand from it :o

Comment: Man, it calls the binary with command line flags you omitted. This is basic shell scripting, far out of the scope of this answer, much more of the according comments.

Comment: I suspect you mean this: ` if [ -f /etc/default/mongod ]; then . /etc/default/mongod; fi ` which confuses me further because when I `ll /etc/default/ ` there is no mongod file on my system :?

Also yea, I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge I am trying to fill.

Comment: There is an init file. But honestly, I don't use Ubuntu ;) Have  look. I am confident you will find it