# Yum update resets MongoDb settings in /etc/init.d/mongod

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm solving a transparent_hugepage/defrag warning in mongodb  [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911634/how-to-avoid-transparent-hugepage-defrag-warning-from-mongodb) by modifying the file /etc/init.d/mongod.

However, whenever I run $sudo yum update (on AWS EC2 instance) , the content of the file gets reset. And the hugepage defrag warning come back.

Is there a way to keep my machine and the mongo package up to date and stay away from the hugepage defrag warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try thts https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic, I didn't and will try it shortly.